# how can get action path of the form in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have update My data with this form

```
<form class="form-vertical" role="form" method="post" action="">
            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('comments') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                <input type="text" name="comments" class="form-control" id="comments" value="{!! $comment->comments ?: '' !!}">
                @if ($errors->has('comments'))
                    <span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('comments') }}</span>
                @endif
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Update Commment</button>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
            {!! method_field('PUT') !!}
        </form>
```

this form routes is

```
Route::put('projects/{projects}/collaborators/{id}',['uses'=>'ProjectCollaboratorsController@update',]);
```

I need how can I give my form action

```
<form class="form-vertical" role="form" method="post" action="">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your route as:

```
Route::put('projects/{projects}/collaborators/{id}',['uses'=>'ProjectCollaboratorsController@update', 'as' => 'projects.collaborators.update']);
```

Then in your form you can do as:

```
<form class="form-vertical" role="form" method="post" action="{{ route('projects.collaborators.update', ['projects' => 1, 'collaborators' => 2]) }}">
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#named-routes)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use [Laravel Collective](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html).

Then you can create forms as simple as `echo Form::open(['action' => 'Controller@method'])`